# Terraform apply fails with "Failed to read ssh private key: no key found"

Tags: terraform

I am using following terraform configuration on windows-10
Terraform v1.0.4
on windows_amd64

- provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.55.0

I am trying to install some packages on ec2 instance using provisioner "remote-exec". In this when i supply private_key in th connection block, i am getting following error message

```
         Failed to read ssh private key: no key found
```

This is how my remote-exec and connection block look like

```
                    terraform {
                    required_providers {
                        aws = {
                        source  = "hashicorp/aws"
                        version = "~> 3.0"
                        }
                    }
                    }
                    resource "aws_instance" sandbox {
                        ami =           "ami-0ff338189efb7ed37"
                        instance_type =     "t3.micro"
                        tags    = {
                            Name =      "sandbox"
                            Description = "sandbox server"
                        }
                            provisioner "remote-exec" {
                            inline = [ "sudo apt update",
                                        "sudo apt install ansible -y" 
                                    ]
                        }
                            connection {
                            type = "ssh"
                            host = self.public_ip
                            user = "ubuntu"
                            private_key = file("C:\\Users\\asdfsd\\Downloads\\asdfsd-ubuntu.pem")
                        }
                        key_name  = aws_key_pair.sandbox_key.id
                        vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.ssh_access.id]
                    }
                    resource "aws_key_pair"  "sandbox_key" {
                        public_key = file("C:\\Users\\asdfsd\\Downloads\\asdfsd-ubuntu-public.pem")
                    }
```

I tried referring to other similar threads on stackoverflow, but they talk about some ${module.path}. I am not sure what this path refers to. Therefore, that solution does not work for me.

Does anyone face similar problem? Any help is much appreciated.

In addition, I tried reading contents of the private key and pass it as a text to the connection block but it did not work either.

```
         locals {
             key_data = file("C:\\Users\\asdfasdf\\Downloads\\asdffa-ubuntu.pem")
         }
         .
         .
         .
         private_key = local.key_data
         .
         .


Best regards,
Amit Joshi.
```

Comment: Can you try with: `/c/Users/asdfasdf/Downloads/asdfasdf-ubuntu.pem`?

Comment: Do you get the same error with the second approach? And can you expand the context of that error message so that it includes the resource that throws the error please? Ideally your Terraform code should also be more complete as mentioned at [mcve]. And finally, are you sure that the key file exists at that path and that the user you are running Terraform as has read access to that file?

Comment: /c/Users/asdfasdf/Downloads/asdfasdf-ubuntu.pem - this did not work.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR i have updated the problem description with actual code. also, the user has access to these files and it is the same user with which terraform is running.

Comment: You haven't expanded the error message to show the full context of the error so it's not clear which resource is throwing that error. Can you expand that please to show the full error output?

Comment: @ydaetskco is this what you are trying to say with expanded output? aws_instance.sandbox: Provisioning with 'remote-exec'...
╷
│ Error: remote-exec provisioner error
│
│   with aws_instance.sandbox,
│   on aws-ec2.tf line 37, in resource "aws_instance" "sandbox":
│   37:     provisioner "remote-exec" {
│
│ Failed to read ssh private key: no key found

Answer (score 0):

On my ubuntu system I am refering to the key without the `.pem` extension.

I faced the same problem when I tried with `.pem` at the end. I don't know if that'll fix the problem since you are on windows but you can try it.

Also try to move the key to the same directory where your tf code is.

Comment: referring to the key without .pem did not really work.

Comment: ```
    ╷
    │ Error: Invalid function argument
    │
    │   on aws-ec2.tf line 47, in resource "aws_instance" "sandbox":
    │   47:         private_key = file("C:\\Users\\asdfasd\\Downloads\\asdfasd-ubuntu")
    │
    │ Invalid value for "path" parameter: no file exists at C:\Users\ajoshi5\Downloads\ajoshi-ubuntu; this function works only with files that are distributed as part
    │ of the configuration source code, so if this file will be created by a resource in this configuration you must instead obtain this result from an attribute of
    │ that resource.
```